# Klein bottle contains Möbius band

Tags: general-topology, klein-bottle, mobius-band, non-orientable-surfaces

I read the following: "The Klein bottle contains a copy of the Möbius band".
I assume this means that there is a subspace of the Klein bottle that is homeomorphic to the Möbius band. How do we obtain the Möbius band from the fundamental polygon of the Klein bottle?
[image]

Comment: In fact _every_ non-orientable two-dimensional manifold has a subspace that is homeomorphic to the Möbius strip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Hint:*

Here's a representation of a Mobius band. Hmmm, what does this suggest...

[image]

Comment: Can we somehow vertically cut out a strip from the Klein bottle? It'll look like the representation of the Mobius band

Comment: Since the red arrows in your diagram correspond to the blue arrows in the original diagram, rather than to the red arrows, I wonder why you made them red instead of blue.

Comment: @iwriteonbananas, yes. If the original square is $[0,1] \times [0,1]$, the Klein bottle equivalence relation is $$(x,y) \sim (1-x,y)$$

So to get a Mobius strip, take for example $[1/3,2/3] \times [0,1]$ under that equivalence.

Comment: @SimonS Of course thank u

Comment: To be more careful, I should say that's one of the Kelin bottle equivalence relations, the one you need to make the Mobius strip. The other is $(0,y) \sim (1,y)$.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't join the red edges together you get what you want, so you can cut the Klein Bottle along the red edge (or what it becomes in the Klein Bottle when the two red edges are identified).

Comment: Thank u. What do u mean by cut the Klein bottle along the red edge?

Comment: @iwriteonbananas You have the net for the Klein bottle. When you identify the two red sides, also draw a red line on the Klein Bottle where they join. If you cut along the line you get the net with the two blue edges identified (and not the red edges). And that is what you want.